# Как выводить текст по середине окна?

Tags: css

У меня есть небольшой код на javascript. Он показывает небольшое окно при загрузке страницы с некоторым текстом. Мне нужно чтоб текст в нутри этого небольшого окна выводился по середине а не по левому краю.

вот код:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            setTimeout("$('#div1').fadeIn('drop');", 500);
            setTimeout("$('#div1').fadeOut('drop');", 3000);
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id='div1' style="display: none; position:absolute; top:10%; left:30%; background-color: grey; border: 1px solid lightblue; width: 650px; padding: 5px;">
<h2>Information bla-bla-bla</h2>
<h2>just do it bla-bla-bla</h2>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Попробуйте `text-align: center`

```
<div id='div1' style="text-align: center; display: none; position:absolute; top:10%; left:30%; background-color: grey; border: 1px solid lightblue; width: 650px; padding: 5px;">
<h2>Information bla-bla-bla</h2>
<h2>just do it bla-bla-bla</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<h2 style="text-align:center">…
```